# Chart JS Zoom Pan

Tags: chart.js, chart.js2

I am using the Chart JS Zoom/Pan Plugin (https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-zoom) and was wondering if there is a way to disable it when there is no data present. The current basic options settings are

```
pan: {
    enabled: true,
    mode: 'x'
},
zoom: {
    enabled: true,
    mode: 'x'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can change this by setting "enabled" to false and/or use chart.resetZoom() [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chartjs-plugin-zoom)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
// since myChart.update() is not working. You need to do this.

var myChartOptions = myChart.options; // need to store in variable.

// check data present
if (data.length > 0) {
    myChartOptions.pan.enabled = true;
    myChartOptions.zoom.enabled = true;
    myChart.options = myChartOptions; // update myChart.options.
}
else {
    myChartOptions.pan.enabled = false;
    myChartOptions.zoom.enabled = false;
    myChart.options = myChartOptions; // update myChart.options.
}
```